# Sessions variable after session_write_close

Tags: php, session

I have just realized that I have consistently been referencing the `$_SESSIONS` superglobal after having called `session_write_close` in many of my scripts.  That is not as moronic as it sounds - the error crept in because the write_close was being called in one included script which I hadn't re-examined in a long time.

A naive assumption would be that this is OK since closing the session should have no effect on the global variable that has already been created - and that the script should work as desired so long as `$_SESSIONS` is only read from rather than written to.

Nevertheless that is no more than a naive assumption and calling `session_write_close` and then using the sessions variable makes no logical sense.  That apart, I am probably treading on thin ice even with the assumption that it is "OK" so long as `$_SESSIONS` is only being read.

Best option as always - seek a few opinions here to clarify the truth!

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php#112681 It’s okay to read from $_SESSION after closing it – but if you accidentally _write_ new data to it (or update existing entries), those changes will not be reflected on the next opening of the session. As long as you don’t do that, you’re OK … but its easy enough to forget.

Comment: That was well spotted - I checked out the docs and somehow managed to miss that.  As you say, it is easy enough to forget that the session has been closed.  I did it thanks to the fact that the closure was in an include file that I had not bothered to examine in a long time.